# Can I change an unmounted partition's type from another partition on the drive?

Tags: partition

On my hard drive I have a largish unused partition that I would like to use.  Trouble is, it's an old Windows partition and I'd prefer to make it a proper Linux partition (I intend using it via LVM if that makes a difference).

So what I'd like to do is re-jig the partition type and reformat it then add it to my already-existing LVM group.

But what I'd really like to do is do this from within my existing Linux distribution running on the same drive.  I'd rather not have to go through the hassle of making/finding a live CD.

So to be clear: the partition that I want to change is *not* mounted, but is on the same drive as my Linux distribution.  Is there a partitioning tool that will do that, and do it safely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You use your favorite partition tool (`fdisk`, `cfdisk`, `parted`) in order to change the partition ID.
2. You make the partition a valid LVM partition with `pvcreate`.
3. You make the new PV available with `vgcreate` or `vgextend`.

Not complicated at all. The worst case would be that you need `partprobe` or a reboot for LVM to recognize the new partition but probably LVM does not give much about the ID anyway.

Changing the ID of an (in that moment and during booting) unused partition is in general a safe operation (for the running Linux; may badly affect other installed OSs though).

Comment: Thanks; the key part is whether or not 1 can be done safely from another partition on the same drive.  All the guides I could find said that modifying the partition table should only be done on a drive that was totally unmounted, but then they were talking about major reorganisation, whereas here I want to keep the same partitions but just change one from Windows to Linux.  So: can I do step 1 whilst other partitions on the same drive are mounted?

Comment: @AndrewStacey That is absolutely safe. The kernel does not re-read the partition table as a whole because the data for partitions which are in use cannot be changed. But that does not mean that the entries for other partitions cannot be updated. And even if they cannot be updated that would not make the operation unsafe.

Comment: So the kernel will not let me do anything that is unsafe; whereupon, if it works then it was safe.  (If only life worked that way!)  Please edit that comment in to your answer (as it's the crucial fact I was missing) so that I can accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewStacey You have misunderstood me: The kernel will usually let you do every possible damage to the system. In this case: It will even allow you to erase the partition table completely, rendering the volume useless. What I meant is: Changing the ID of an unused partition is safe. But if you intend to change an ID but accidentally do something different (potentially dangerous) then nothing is going to stop you from that. The risk is very low but if you are unexperienced it makes sense to make a backup of the partition table and store it on a different physical medium.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I think I get it now.  Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I added a respective hint to the answer.